# Recording Crash using Crashlytics AFTER overridin JSExceptionHandler (React Native)_

Tags: react-native, exception, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics (Natively) in React Native.
In RN, I'm overriding the JSExceptionHandler to use NativeModules and call out to my MyCrashHandler.

MyCrashHandler does the with Crashlytics reportError.. but this is only good if I THEN have a crash.
I can't have a Crashlytics crash because I already overrode the JSExceptionHandler.

How do I force Crashlytics to send my events? Maybe I need to use Firebase logging instead?

Comment: Why not use https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/android?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wait for a crash to know that `Crashlytics` is working. You can use the `SDK` to [force a crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash) by adding the following code to your app

```
Button crashButton = new Button(this);
crashButton.setText("Crash!");
```

Also, you can use your own API like this:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.start(withAPIKey: "YOUR_API_KEY")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom crash report by writing code in native iOS and Android. Please check the following the link for it.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios